# How to get quantize values

Tags: d3.js

is there a way to get the start and end values of the quantizes of an quantize scale.
The range is defined by 5 colors ans the domain by d3.min and d3.max function on my data from an json file.
I need them for my legend of an choropleth map.
Thank you for helping.

Carsten

Thats my code

```
var quantizecolors = ["#d7191c","#fdae61","#ffffbf", "#a6d96a","#1a9641"];
var colorEnerg = d3.scale.quantize().range(quantizecolors);
colorEnerg.domain([
                            d3.min(collection.features, function(d){return d.properties.EB/d.properties.BEVZ;}),
                            d3.max(collection.features, function(d){return d.properties.EB/d.properties.BEVZ;})
                            ]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you're asking about the minimum and maximum domain values. Apart from saving them when you're setting them, you can also call `colorEnerg.domain()` without any values, which will return the array `[min, max]`.

You can get the position of the breaks by computing the number and position of intervals:

```
var dom = colorEnerg.domain(),
    l = (dom[1] - dom[0])/colorEnerg.range().length,
    breaks = d3.range(0, colorEnerg.range().length).map(function(i) { return i * l; });
```

Comment: Thank you, this will give me the start and end of the whole domain. What I´m searching for are the values of each of the five parts.